# Detecting if set time has elapsed since date in Django model

Tags: python, django, datetime, models

This code just keeps giving me errors. I have a field (datetime) in my Django model called `invite_sent` and another field in the same model called `check_time` Check time is the amount of time after `invite sent` that a certain action should occur. For some reason, my code wont work.

models.py

```
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    summery = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    complete = models.BooleanField()
    invite_sent = models.DateTimeField() #<-----------
    check_time = models.IntegerField() #<-----------
    on = models.ForeignKey("Member", related_name="turn", blank=True,  null=True)
```

views.py

```
def check_time():
    games = Game.objects.filter(complete = False)
    for g in games:
        hours = (datetime.datetime - g.invite_sent)/60/60 # trying to get hours between now and then
        if not hours > g.check_time: #stuff beyond this is not really important to the issue
            continue
        send_overtime(g)
        set_on(g)
        send_invite(g)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have problems at this line `hours = (datetime.datetime - g.invite_sent)/60/60`

- you should use `datetime.datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.datetime` (its a module object you have to call `.now()`)
- subtracting two `datetime` objects gives a `timedelta` objects which has a method `.total_seconds()` use that to convert to hours

so the buggy line of code should be:

```
hours = (datetime.datetime.now() - g.invite_sent.replace(tzinfo=None)).total_seconds() / 60 / 60
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get this error `can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`

Comment: ok django its returning `offset-aware datetimes` which is timezone aware, is timezone info is important in your case? please answer so that i can update the solution accordingly

Comment: Timezone is not important. In fact, it is actually harmfull to the way the program should run. (So it shouldn't be time-zone aware)

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you don't want timezone aware datetimes from django then you should set `USE_TZ = False` in your settings file

Comment: clear the data in tables and start again. Because old data is timezone aware, doing `.replace(tzinfo=None)` only disable timezone info, don't forget to change `USE_TZ = False` in settings file.

Comment: You can use timezone aware datetimes too. Instead using `datetime.datetime.now()` use `django.utils.timezone.now()`.

Comment: @Hvandracas i know but if you read comments, the OP has said `Timezone is not important. In fact, it is actually harmfull to the way the program should run`